# How to connect to redis with dokku and flask?

Tags: flask, redis, dokku

I wanted to use redis with dokku and flask. First issue was installing current version of dokku, i am using latest version from repo now.

Second problem is showing in Flask debugger:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError
ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to None:6379. Connection refused.
```

I set redis url and port in Flask:

```
app.config['REDIS_URL'] = 'IP:32768'
```

-----> Checking status of Redis
    remote: Found image redis/landing
    remote: Checking status...stopped.
    remote: Launching redis/landing...COMMAND: docker run -v /home/dokku/.redis/volume-landing:/var/lib/redis -p 6379 -d redis/landing /bin/start_redis.sh
    -----> Setting config vars
           REDIS_URL:  redis://IP:6379
           REDIS_IP:   IP
           REDIS_PORT: 6379

Any idea? REDIS_URL should be set in different way?

This code works ok in localhost:
https://github.com/kwikiel/bounce
(with ['REDIS_IP'] = '172.17.0.13' set to 127.0.0.1)

Problem appears when i try to connect with redis dokku.

Comment: How are you connecting to Redis? What library are you using. It doesn't appear to be using the setting you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to use redis with flask and dokku:

1. Install redis plugin:

   cd /var/lib/dokku/plugins

   git clone https://github.com/ohardy/dokku-redis redis

   dokku plugins-install
2. Link your redis container to application container

   dokku redis:create [name of app container]

You will receive info about environmental variables that you will have to set - for example:

```
   Host: 172.17.0.91
   Public port: 32771
```

Then set these settings in Flask (or other framework)

```
app.config['REDIS_URL'] =  'redis://172.17.0.91:6379' 
app.config['REDIS_IP'] = '172.17.0.91'                                      
app.config['REDIS_PORT'] = '6379'
```

Complete example of redis database used with Flask app (A/B testing in Flask):

https://github.com/kwikiel/bounce

Comment: this IP address may change, if you restart the system, for instance. isn't there some DNS configuration?